# Snippet in Google Search contains "An error occurred. Try watching this video on www.youtube.com", but I don't have any video

Tags: youtube, seo, google-search

Why do i get this message when I try to search my website with google?
[image]

I don't have any kind of video on my index page....
All I have is login form logo and registration form and `<h1>` and `<p>`

My meta says:

```
<meta name="description" content="DigyBridg free social website">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Fun, people, photos, videos, statuses, links, db, dbp, digybridg, digy, bridg">
    <meta name="author" content="Sasa Orasanin">
```

Why is my main title link An error occurred?
And same with this for video under that.

Comment: I think this a good questions for the devs at google. Visit the google product forums

Comment: Also I am connected with ad sense and statistics

Comment: @Jonasw I posted there as well....

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into this issue myself, and found the cause:

If you embed a YouTube video, using an iframe, and inspect the source of the iframe, you will see a section like this:

```
<noscript>

    <div class="player-unavailable">
        <h1 class="message">An error occurred.</h1>
    </div>

    [...]
</noscript>
```

Since Google doesn't always use the text in the `<title>` tag you supply, and since that error message is within an `<h1>`, I think Google is promoting YouTube's error message into the title, because unlike most browsers, it takes the `<noscript>` section into account.

To fix this, I'd suggest including the iframe using JavaScript only- this has the downside of hiding the video completely from visitors without JavaScript, but prevents the `<noscript>` section from being served.

(I'm not 100% sure this would work though, as Googlebot may well be sophisticated enough to take some JavaScript page manipulation into account these days.)

Another alternative may be to craft a more appropriate page title, which Google will be less inclined to alter.